# Rails 6.0 Error: DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionView::Base instances should be constructed with a lookup context, assignments, and a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionView::Base instances should be constructed with a lookup context, assignments, and a controller. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/<me>/RubymineProjects/<myproject>/config/environment.rb:7)
```

That file only has these lines:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

How do I find out where the issue is? I'm sure it's something stupid... This is a project that was migrated from Rails 4.2

Comment: Have you searched your codebase for instances of ActionView::Base? This answer might help you on how to rectify this deprecation warning if you do have instances of ActionView::Base. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63865988/7485031

Comment: I had seen that answer, but I have no "ActionView::Base" anywhere in my code.

Comment: When are you getting this? Every environment, or just test? Most likely error is thrown from some gem initializer, we'll need full error backtrace.

Comment: I get this in any environment. Please tell me how to get that full error backtrace - this is happening in the dev environment with debug mode on already.